# qsort Segmentation Fault structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault, segment

So, my first question here, please be patient with me:

My task is to sort an array of structs (name, surname and another struct for the birthday, which consists of the year, month, day). I have to sort by birthdate and by using qsort.
My problem is, I looked up everything about qsort but i am not quite sure if my implementation is correct since I am new to C. I can create the executable program but it is not giving my any result only Segmentation Fault.

Here is my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int (*compfn) (const void*, const void*);

typedef struct {
    unsigned year, month, day;
} date_t;

typedef struct {
    char name[32];
    char surname[32];
    date_t birthday;
}person_t;

typedef struct {
    unsigned n;
    unsigned cap;
    person_t *arr;
} persons_t;


int compare(person_t *a, person_t *b){
  if(a->birthday.year!=b->birthday.year){
    return a->birthday.year-b->birthday.year;
  }else{
    if(a->birthday.month!=b->birthday.month){
      return a->birthday.month-b->birthday.month;
    }else{
      return a->birthday.day-b->birthday.day;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc <= 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "syntax: %s <inputfile>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE* f = fopen(argv[1], "rt");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open file %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    persons_t persons;
    persons.n = 0;
    persons.cap = 0;
    persons.arr = NULL;

    person_t p;
    while (fscanf(f, "%s %s %4u-%2u-%2u", p.name, p.surname,
            &p.birthday.year, &p.birthday.month, &p.birthday.day) == 5) {

        if (persons.n == persons.cap) {
            persons.cap = persons.cap == 0 ? 1 : 2 * persons.cap;
            persons.arr = realloc(persons.arr, persons.cap * sizeof(persons.arr[0]));
        }

        persons.arr[persons.n++] = p;
    }

    int nitems = persons.cap*sizeof(persons.arr[0]);
    int size = sizeof(persons.arr[0]);
    qsort(persons.arr, nitems, size, (compfn)compare);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < persons.n; i++) {
        person_t *p = persons.arr + i;
        printf("%s %s %4u-%2u-%2u\n",
                p->name, p->surname,
                p->birthday.year, p->birthday.month, p->birthday.day);
    }



    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

I hope someone can help me,
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: When you ran it under a debugger, which line generated the fault?

Comment: This line - `qsort(persons.arr, nitems, size, (compfn)compare);` - The compiler told you it was wrong, but you just shoved in a cast.  Don't do that.  Instead, declare the function as taking `void*` arguments and do the cast inside the function.  Not sure if that's *the* problem, but it is a problem.

Comment: You may find it easier to start with a simpler `qsort`, say, one where you just sort integers. Once you understand that, you can move to more advanced things like sorting structures. (Also, that sort comparison function is not going to work because you are subtracting unsigned values [which is never negative], so you are never going to return a negative value when `a` is less than `b`.)

Comment: why was this downvoted? Seems like a pretty decent attempt at a first question

Comment: @DavidAnderton Probably because there was no evidence of any attempt to debug the program. You can't just post code and say "It doesn't work."

Comment: Try debugging the program. Look at the values you are passing to `qsort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as `_t`-suffixed identifiers go, according to the C standard they're reserved for the implementation (e.g. your compiler, and/or your standard library). It's very possible that your implementation already has a `date_t` type, and your code might be causing some kind of mischief. If you wish to avoid subtly and dangerously clashing identifiers wreaking all sorts of havoc, it's probably best to avoid them. Not to worry, you could always use '`_s`' to denote a `struct` type instead!

---

Whenever you're declaring a variable that represents an index within an array, use `size_t` as the type!

---

> ```
> int compare(person_t *a, person_t *b){
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> qsort(persons.arr, nitems, size, (compfn)compare);
> ```

According to the [qsort manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html), the argument given as the comparator function should be an `int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)`, and that's what you've given since you've cast to `(compfn)`. As far as `qsort` is aware that function accepts two `const void *` arguments, which might differ in representation to `person_t *` arguments. This could certainly cause segfaults. Don't lie about the type of `compare`. Change it to look more like:

```
int compare(const void *x, const void *y) {
    const person_s *a = x, *b = y;
    /* ... */
}
```

... and you won't need the cast *or* the typedef.

Next, onto return values for that function. I have used implementations where-by lexically illogical return values cause segmentation faults. For example, if `a <= b` and `b <= c`, then `a <= c`, but your code doesn't guarantee this. In fact, using your code it is possible that `a <= b`, `b <= c` and `a > c`. I recommend making sure your code guarantees correspondence between the return value and lexical order. You can do so by returning 1 for greater than, 0 for equal to or -1 for less than.

```
#define lexical_order(x,y) ((x > y) - (x < y))
int compare(const void *x, const void *b){
  const person_s *a = x, *b = y;
  return a->birthday.year != b->birthday.year   ? lexical_order(a->birthday.year,  b->birthday.year)
       : a->birthday.month != b->birthday.month ? lexical_order(a->birthday.month, b->birthday.month)
                                                : lexical_order(a->birthday.day,   b->birthday.day);
}
```

---

I'm sure you're aware that you should be checking the return value of `realloc`... For example:

```
void *temp = realloc(persons.arr, persons.cap * sizeof(persons.arr[0]));
if (temp == NULL) {           /* If we don't check return value prior *
                               * to assigning to persons.arr, we      *
                               * might leak some memory...            */
    puts("Error in realloc");
    free(persons.arr);
    exit(-1);
}
persons.arr = temp;
```

---

Finally, and most importantly (this is probably your error), are you sure about this?

```
int nitems = persons.cap*sizeof(persons.arr[0]);
```

If you mean to pass this as the number of items to `qsort` (which is usual), then I think that should be:

```
size_t nitems = persons.n;
```

P.S. In case you missed it the second time, you should probably audit your code to make sure you're using `size_t` to store array indexes only.

P.P.S. Don't forget to `free(persons);` at the end of your program, so you don't end up with reports of memory leaks when you use `valgrind`...

P.P.P.S. `valgrind` is awesome!

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the optimal answer. I really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1):

So you are allocating our array by doubling its size whenever needed, using persons.cap, but you are not filling all its elements, are you?

From your code, the actual number of persons is nitems = persons.n, not persons.cap. What if you retry your code with nitems=persons.n?

If you have unfilled elements in your array, it means the strings inside them are arbitrary (i.e person.name), so probably not null-terminated, and the crash will occur when you try to display them.